# Why is there random text in my document, even though I have not written it?

Tags: errors

chchchch somehow appears at the start of my document, even though I have not written it anywhere. There is also a "no \begin{document}" error, even though it is there in my writing.

My code is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.25inch]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{UP101L-Experiment 6-Coupled Torsional Pendulum}
\author{Jyotiraditya Mishra}
\date{Janurary 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

[image: this is at the start of my document, before the title page.]

[image: I get this error as well.]

Comment: This is caused by a typo in the option of `geometry`. The unit inch is abbreviated as `in`, thus the correct code would be `\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}`.

Comment: @leandriis Why not turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 3):

This issue is caused by a typo in the options of `geometry`. The unit inch is correctly abbreviated with `in` instead of `inch`:

```
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
```